# How to fix a view on the top of the layout and make collapse rest of layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to design a layout like blew application.I want to fix a `VideoView` on top of my layout and rest of layout behave `collapsing` state. I write this code but I did not get the result.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.DetailMyCourseActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/videoView">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:titleEnabled="false">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitleCourse"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:text="عنوان دوره دروه"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtInstructor"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitleCourse"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="علیرضا عزیزی"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabTextColor="#fff"
                app:tabIndicator="@android:color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="1.5dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabGravity="fill"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_layout">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/txt_description_course"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by **rest of layout behave collapsing state** Can you please elaborate a little bit more? Or add some existing applications sample.

Comment: In the udemy application -> option my course ->layout single detail my course

Comment: I have solved your problem.

Comment: So, please put your answer

Comment: I have submitted my answer. Please check that out. If there's any problem to understand let me know.

Comment: Hey, @sarina didn't work my answer?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the full project - [github url](https://github.com/alamincmt/android/tree/master/MiddleLayoutScrollable)

Or you may try with this snippet of code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/tabanim_maincontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordiLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/videoview">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <LinearLayout
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#ffffff">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Your topics title goes here. "
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="subtitle goes here "
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/tab_viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There is a blank white view in the bottom of layout. how to remove it?

Comment: Just change the **CoordinatorLayout height wrap_content to match_parent** and the white blank view will be gone. 

I have edited my answer. Just take a look.

Comment: Ok the  white blank removed but I have another problem.When I scrolling down inside layout and go to end of layout and again scroll up to first item of reyclerview, rather than scrolling recyclerveiw, middle appbarlayout open. Generally scrolling behavior That's not what I expect.Perhaps should I use NestedScrollView? Please Compare the behavior of the Udemy app with this app to understand what I mean.